# Rebuilding Tab Delimited text stream due to Impossible to remove Carriage Returns

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, clipboard

We have an Oracle database with a documentum front end, and has a function called Multi-Edit, which outputs 200 records max as raw text which we can then paste into Excel, edit, and then re-submit, provided they are tab delimited in a precise way.

This is all well and good until the record submitter enters a carriage return into a freetext field, which Excel treats as a new line, and totally wrecks the formatting for re-entry into the database.

A recent change seems to have made performing a find/replace of CR+LF on the data stored in the clipboard impossible.

I have been doing it recently with this nifty bit of AHK script I found online:

```
#h::
stringreplace,Clipboard,Clipboard,`r`n,&A_Space&,all
Return
```

Pasting the data into Notepad, copying it again, and then applying my find/replace script doesn't work.

Pasting the data into Notepad++ and copying it again, then applying the script  works too well. Each record line ends with a CRLF, so I need to keep some and remove the rest!

This makes less likely that my method worked in the first place. Unless it was removing user entered CRLF and not the system entered ones. Implying they have some property of their own.

Something is preventing these carriage returns from being removed. Is it possible they are being outputted not as carriage returns, but as a strange equivalent, and re-interpreted as CRLF by Windows software?

Notepad seems to invisibly store whatever this character is, while Notepad++ does not.

My VBA solution would be to remove all the returns and use the tabs to create and array, then dump the whole array into Excel.

This method will still stumble on the possibility of the record containing a TAB in the free text part of a record, but I think this is quite rare.

I think what I need to do is assess each part of the array and either:

- remove the CRLF
- if it's tab position 49 in that row, split the array into two array values, add it to the array position immediately next to it and shunt the array along.

I've managed to come up with some crude code for the purpose of putting data from the clipboard into an array and writing the values to Excel, but it has problems. I've tried replacing the vbCRLF with vbTab, but it's a crude start.

```
Option Base 1
Sub clipcase()
Dim wrdArray() As String
Dim finalArray(201, 49) As String
Dim RecordCount As Integer
Dim maxCol, maxRow As Integer

updatesOff

maxCol = 49
maxRow = 201
maxCell = maxRow * maxCol

Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject

DataObj.GetFromClipboard

strPaste = DataObj.GetText(1)
strPaste = Replace(strPaste, vbCrLf, vbTab)

wrdArray() = Split(strPaste, vbTab)

RecordCount = UBound(wrdArray) / 49
RecordCount = Application.Round(RecordCount, 0)

        For i = 1 To RecordCount + 1
            For j = 1 To 49
                finalArray(i, j) = wrdArray(k)
                k = k + 1
                If k > UBound(wrdArray) Then GoTo dump
            Next j
        Next i

dump:
For i = 1 To UBound(finalArray, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(finalArray, 2)
        Cells(i, j).Value2 = finalArray(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

updatesOn

End Sub

Sub updatesOff()
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub

Sub updatesOn()
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: there are editors that deal with CR or CR/LF etc Unix CR etc Prograqmmer's file editor, BBedit, TextWrangler come to mind which can probably do want you need...

Comment: That sounds bloody perfect for identifying the problem! Unfortunately I'll never be allowed to install any software like that in the office.

Comment: It will certainly satisfy my curiosity... but I think an excel VBA solution is really the only viable option.